# Send newsletter to Gmail having div with background image

Tags: css, html, gmail, newsletter

I can send newsletters to email accounts. I am using div for containing the text. Now, I want to set a background image to the div as demonstrated in the code below:

```
string containerDiv = @"<div width=200 height=500 style=""background:url('http://www.instantfetch.com/Content/restaurant_logos/promo1.gif');"">";
```

But the problem is, my Yahoo account can fetch the image in its body but my Gmail account cannot. Below are two screenshot: I used 'Inspect element' option in Google Chrome to get the rendered div in my browser.

Yahoo:
[image]

Gmail:
[image]

**My question is what is the problem in my code? Why can Yahoo get the URL properly and render it but Gmail cannot get the URL and cannot render it? What should I do if I want to display the background image in Gmail as well?**

Comment: If that's the kind of BG image you're including, I'd rather be reading (and be ABLE to read it) on gmail than seeing that ugly blob in Yahoo...

Comment: I see at least missing opening parenthesis after `url`.

Comment: i pasted the right code now.but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail does not support background images.

It's created many problems here and caused redesign due to the limitation. It's not your code... it's Gmail.

Comment: yes. you are right. i have tested so many ways last day but couldn't make it happen. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bracket after "background:url".

Should be 
style=""background:url('http://www.instantfetch.com/Content/restaurant_logos/promo1.gif');""

I guess Yahoo is overlooking your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The "" might be causing the issue. Try this:

```
string containerDiv = @"<div width=200 height=500 style=\"background:url('http://www.instantfetch.com/Content/restaurant_logos/promo1.gif');\">";
```